# How to set MaxUploadSize in MultipartResolver (SpringBoot Gradle project)

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload, gradle, spring-boot, multipartform-data

Here i'm working with file upload with KB size to GB size. In MvcConfig.java, while setting,

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver() {
    final CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(-1);
    return commonsMultipartResolver;
}
```

to accept files with any size, I can upload file with large size from MB to GB, but it wont accept small files with KB size. Please suggest a way to accept any size file.

In MvcConfig :

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final int MEGABYTE_IN_BYTES = 0;


  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
     registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("index");
     registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
     registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login"); 
  }

  @Bean
  public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver() {
     final CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
     commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(-1);
     return commonsMultipartResolver;
  }

  /*@Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean multipartFilterRegistrationBean() {
     final MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
     final FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new   FilterRegistrationBean(multipartFilter);
     filterRegistrationBean.addInitParameter("multipartResolverBeanName", "commonsMultipartResolver");
     return filterRegistrationBean;
  }

  @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
  public StandardServletMultipartResolver resolver() {
     return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
  }*/
}
```

In controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
ModelAndView handleFile1Upload(@RequestParam("userName") String name,
        Model Model,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @Validated MultipartFile file
        ,@RequestParam("delimiter") String delimiter
        ,@RequestParam("format") String format
        ,@RequestParam("headerPresent") String headerPresent
        final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {


    System.out.println("working...");
    System.out.println("selected file is::::"+file);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            status = "fail";
        }finally{
            if (!status.equals("fail"));
        }

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/home");
}
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: can you describe the problem more. e.g. provide stacktrace, your controller code, client code.

Comment: Sure, i have updated my question with controller code, please check.